# Response code from GET request to jsp page using SimpleFormController

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, jsp

I am trying to set up a http responder for incoming GET requests using a JSP page with a SimpleFormController.

I am receiving a GET request from a third party company, who are expecting a 200 http response back. However, even though my JSP is basically blank, when a GET request come in, it bypasses my JSP page and is automatically submitted to the onSubmit method in my controller and a http response of 201 is sent back.

How can I send a 200 response back, instead of 201?

Thanks,

Dave

Answer (score 0):

If the onsubmit method is being called, it sounds to me like they are not sending a get request, but doing a post.

Make sure they are sending a get request.

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks for your reply. You were quite right, they are doing a POST. Any ideas why my server is responding with 201 rather than 200?

Comment: I found this googling: "201: Following a POST command, this indicates success, but the text of the response line indicates the URL of the new document.". So I guess if they send a get command they'll get a 200 response.